# Code Igniter url routing question (using trailing slashes)

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, codeigniter, url-routing

I am brand new to codeIgniter.

I am very particular about urls on the sites that I develop. Is it possible to create these sorts of urls? Generally sites I develop have an integrated admin interface as well with **new, edit or delete added onto the end of the url** following a slash.

Here are some hypothetical examples (one with an admin url):

**top level pages (no trailing slash)**

```
site.com/about
site.com/contact
site.com/contact/edit
```

**section index lists (lists have trailing slash)**

```
site.com/blog/
site.com/products/
site.com/products/edit
```

**section pages (lists have trailing slash)**

```
site.com/blog/first-post
site.com/products/best-product
site.com/products/new
site.com/products/best-product/delete
```

**section categories**

```
site.com/blog/code-questions/
site.com/products/red-products/
site.com/products/red-products/delete
```

the first problem I see is sending a url with trailing slash to a different controller then without one. Since you can't add them in the routing file. For instance with top level pages how would I know to call the Pages controller? how do I tell them apart from section index lists? I can't add trailing slashes in routes.php!

```
site.com/about
site.com/blog/
```

same with the section pages vs categories.

generally I have done this in the past with an .htaccess file.

**some examples of how I structure htaccess files for urls in the past in my own applications**

```
RewriteRule ^new$ index.php?static&new
RewriteRule ^edit$ index.php?edit
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?static&post=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/edit$ index.php?static&edit=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/$ index.php?section=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/new$ index.php?section=$1&new
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?section=$1&post=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/$ index.php?section=$1&category=$2
```

Is there anyway to do this with codeIgniter? Should I just slather rewrite rules on top of the controller generated urls? Is it possible to do this with the routing.php file? **If codeIgniter doesn't do this, could you suggest a framework that can?**

**Also How do I handle using hyphens in the url when tied to the controller class name?**

Comment: The following fork that includes HMVC support allows you to be strict with how you use trailing slashes: https://github.com/Bigwebmaster/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Answer (score 2):

CodeIgniter has a pretty nice way of handling URI routing (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).

By default if you use CodeIgniter's own .htaccess (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html), all requests made into pretty segments.

You could easily use CodeIgniter's routing.php file to generate these URL's you're after. Please refer to their very easy to follow documentation at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/.

Comment: $routing['blog/view/:num'] = 'section/blog/view/$1';
$routing['products/:num'] = 'section/products/view/$1';

Comment: If I have understood right, you want just a trailing slash to denote the action to be different? I'm not sure if this is a very practical way to do what you're trying to do. I would rather use something like your "/new" segment.

Comment: That is correct. so that site.com/([a-z0-9\-]+) would load the TopPages controller and site.com/([a-z0-9\-]+)/ would load the blog controller and so on.

Comment: Okay. I don't see why you would want to do that. You could do: $routing[':any'] = 'TopPages/$1'; $routing['blog/:any'] = 'blog/$1'; ?

Comment: I would like to change the following url http://konzertagentur-koerner.de/index.php/Homepage/getBioH/Andras-Adorjan to http://konzertagentur-koerner.de/index.php/Andras-Adorjan or even better http://konzertagentur-koerner.de/Andras-Adorjan . I use $route['Homepage/getBioH/(:any)'] = 'Homepage/getBioH/$1';
but it does not work (404 error). Maybe $1 only works for numbers and I have to use regexp, because "Andras-Adorjan" is a string?

Comment: to add:I cannot add a htaccess with rewrite.. because of my provider 1und1 which does not allow it. So I cannot do the rewrite?

Comment: What I did now:$route['Andras-Adorjan'] = 'Homepage/getBioH/Andras-Adorjan'; there is no 404 error, but the correct page is not shown when entering koerner.li/index.php/Andras-Adorjan However, this is working:$route['Homepag'] = 'Homepage/getConcerts';